# Angular $http service / controller to JSONP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, jsonp

Due to my cross domain errors, I am trying to convert my $http call to a JSONP one.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I'm a beginner and having extracted my GET service from my controller, I'm struggling with finding the spot where to change $http to $http.jsonp(url) based on the Angular documentation

Here's my **service.js**:

```
.service('NCAAF',function($http, $ionicLoading) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...',
        delay: 300
      })
      return $http (
      {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/[key]?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
        headers: {
              'authorization': 'Bearer [auth]'
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

and **controller.js**:

```
.controller('NCAAFCtrl', function ($scope, NCAAF, $ionicPopup, $ionicLoading) {
  var doGet = function() {

    NCAAF.get().
      success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
        $ionicLoading.hide();
      }).
      error(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'Something went wrong',
          template: 'Try reloading in a few seconds.'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function() {
          console.log('Fix this ish');
        });
      }).
       finally(function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
      });
    };
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    doGet();
  };

  doGet();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONP can make you do cors request ,but that doesn't mean you will be able to get correct response.

JSONP requires you to wrap your JSON response into a Javascript function call.
When you do a JSONP the request , query string will set a parameter called
'callback' that will tell your server how to wrap the JSON response.

The server should use the callback parameter from the request string to set the
response accordingly.

So the response should be

```
callback([ {“access_token”: “asdfsd”, “expires”: “86400" ,"type" : "bearer"}
]);
```

In angular it will look like

```
angular.callbacks._0([ {“access_token”: “asdfsd”, “expires”: “86400" ,“type” :
“bearer”} ]);
```

But just for your information about how to make jsonp call ,change your code

```
return $http (
      {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/[key]?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',
        headers: {
              'authorization': 'Bearer [auth]'
        }
      });
```

to

```
 return $http.jsonp('https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/[key]?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',{
headers: {
              'authorization': 'Bearer [auth]'
        }
});
```